# What's the easiest way to get a user's full name on a Linux/POSIX system?

Tags: database, linux, shell, posix, user-accounts

I could grep through /etc/passwd but that seems onerous.  'finger' isn't installed and I'd like to avoid that dependency.  This is for a program so it would be nice if there was some command that let you just access user info.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You don't specify a programming language, so I'll assume you want to use the shell; here's **an answer for Posix shells**.

Two steps to this: get the appropriate record, then get the field you want from that record.

First, getting the account record is done by **querying the `passwd` table**:

```
$ user_name=foo
$ user_record="$(getent passwd $user_name)"
$ echo "$user_record"
foo:x:1023:1025:Fred Nurk,,,:/home/foo:/bin/bash
```

For hysterical raisins, the full name of the user is recorded in a field called the **[“GECOS” field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field)**; to complicate matters, this field often has its own structure with the **full name as just one of several optional sub-fields**. So anything that wants to get the full name from the account record needs to parse both these levels.

```
$ user_record="$(getent passwd $user_name)"
$ user_gecos_field="$(echo "$user_record" | cut -d ':' -f 5)"
$ user_full_name="$(echo "$user_gecos_field" | cut -d ',' -f 1)"
$ echo "$user_full_name"
Fred Nurk
```

Your **programming language probably has a library function** to do this in fewer steps. In C, you'd use the ‘getpwnam’ function and then parse the GECOS field.

Comment: hysterical raisins?

Comment: Didn't work for me. But this did: `getent passwd | grep "$USER" | cut -d":" -f5 | cut -d"," -f1`

Comment: Use grep "^$USER:" or getent passwd $USER to not match all usernames containing the name of the current user

Comment: Great answer. Here's another one-liner based on your answer that's suitable to insert somewhere in eg. /etc/profile.d
export FULL_USER_NAME="$(getent passwd $USER | cut -d ':' -f 5 | cut -d ',' -f 1)"

Answer (score 33):

On a modern glibc system, use this command:

```
getent passwd "username" | cut -d ':' -f 5
```

That'll get you the `passwd` entry of the specified user, independent of the underlying NSS module.

Read the [manpage of `getent`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?getent).

---

If you're already programming, you can use the `getpwnam()` C-Function:

```
struct passwd *getpwnam(const char *name);
```

The `passwd` struct has a `pw_gecos` member which should contain the full name of the user.

Read the [manpage of `getpwnam()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam).

---

Be aware that many systems use this field for more than the full name of the user. The most common convention is to use a comma (`,`) as separator within the field and place the users real name first.

Comment: So typically the command to get only the user's real name is `getent passwd $USER | cut -d ':' -f 5 | cut -d ',' -f 1`

Comment: With double quotes around `$USER`, in case it contains special characters, and without quotes around `:` and `,`: `getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d, -f1`

Comment: does not work `getent passwd "${USER}" | cut -d: -f5` will return `,,,` on a non sudo. EDIT: I think because the created did not have name.

Answer (score 11):

Combination of other answers, tested on minimal Debian/Ubuntu installations:

```
getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d ':' -f 5 | cut -d ',' -f 1
```

Comment: There are no practical reasons to invoke a subshell for `whoami`, you can use any username directly as an argument. And if _must_ use a subshell, please don't advocate backsticks, use `$()`. But in this case `"$USER"` makes much more sene

Answer (score 9):

Just in case you want to do this from C, try something like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Get full name of a user, given their username. Return 0 for not found,
   -1 for error, or 1 for success. Copy name to `fullname`, but only up
   to max-1 chars (max includes trailing '\0'). Note that if the GECOS
   field contains commas, only up to to (but not including) the first comma
   is copied, since the commas are a convention to add more than just the
   name into the field, e.g., room number, phone number, etc. */
static int getfullname(const char *username, char *fullname, size_t max)
{
    struct passwd *p;
    size_t n;

    errno = 0;
    p = getpwnam(username);
    if (p == NULL && errno == 0)
        return 0;
    if (p == NULL)
        return -1;
    if (max == 0)
        return 1;
    n = strcspn(p->pw_gecos, ",");
    if (n > max - 1)
        n = max - 1;
    memcpy(fullname, p->pw_gecos, n);
    fullname[n] = '\0';
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    int ret;
    char fullname[1024];

    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        ret = getfullname(argv[i], fullname, sizeof fullname);
        if (ret == -1)
            printf("ERROR: %s: %s\n", argv[i], strerror(errno));
        else if (ret == 0)
            printf("UNKONWN: %s\n", argv[i]);
        else
            printf("%s: %s\n", argv[i], fullname);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
getent passwd eutl420 | awk -F':' '{gsub(",", "",$5); print $5}'
```

Answer (score 4):

The top two answers can be combined in one line:

```
getent passwd <username> | cut -d ':' -f 5 | cut -d ',' -f 1
```

Answer (score 2):

My code works in bash and ksh, but not dash or old Bourne shell. It reads the other fields too, in case you might want them.

```
IFS=: read user x uid gid gecos hm sh < <( getent passwd $USER )
name=${gecos%%,*}
echo "$name"
```

You could also scan the whole /etc/passwd file. This works in plain Bourne shell, in 1 process, but not so much with LDAP or what.

```
while IFS=: read user x uid gid gecos hm sh; do
  name=${gecos%%,*}
  [ $uid -ge 1000 -a $uid -lt 60000 ] && echo "$name"
done < /etc/passwd
```

On the other hand, using tools is good.  And C is good too.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I figured it on Linux to get the full name into a variable was:

```
u_id=`id -u`
uname=`awk -F: -vid=$u_id '{if ($3 == id) print $5}' /etc/passwd`
```

Then just simple use the variable, ex: `$ echo $uname`

Answer (score -1):

Take 1:

```
$ user_name=sshd
$ awk -F: "\$1 == \"$user_name\" { print \$5 }" /etc/passwd
Secure Shell Daemon
```

However, passwd database supports special character '&' in the gecos, which should replaced with capitalized value of user name:

```
$ user_name=operator
$ awk -F: "\$1 == \"$user_name\" { print \$5 }" /etc/passwd
System &
```

Most of answers here (except for finger solution) do not respect &.
If you want to support this case, then you'll need a more complicated script.

Take 2:

```
$ user_name=operator
$ awk -F: "\$1 == \"$user_name\" { u=\$1; sub(/./, toupper(substr(u,1,1)), u);
    gsub(/&/, u, \$5); print \$5 }" /etc/passwd
System Operator
```

Answer (score -2):

The good old *finger* may also help :-)

```
finger $USER |head -n1 |cut -d : -f3
```

Comment: OP already mentioned finger wasn't installed at least a year before yo posted this answer ;)